Installing OpenProject on WHM / Cpanel but not sure where to go from there
I'm trying to figure out how to install openProject on my bluehost vps.  I have that server running websites already and thought I would try to get a project manager going as well.
The server is running AlmaLinux v9.5.0 STANDARD  cPanel Version  124.0.
I did the install and had 2 errors, but want to confirm I did the setup properly.
I have root access to my server at example.com/whm.  I have a full whm account there and my dev sites (example.dev) are run under a separate cPanel account. I want the projects to run on my dev account as projects.example.dev.
I installed postgres
I went into my cpanel for example.dev and created a subdomain projects.example.dev.  (this site has an ssl and is publicly reachable.)
I created a db and attached a user with PostgreSQL Database Wizard in cpanel.
I then went back to my terminal in ROOT WHM and ran these commands:
Following this link for openproject: https://www.openproject.org/docs/installation-and-operations/installation/packaged/#centos-9--rhel-9
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/openproject.repo \
  https://dl.packager.io/srv/opf/openproject/stable/15/installer/el/9.repo

then this
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled crb
# sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel{,-next}-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

lastly this
sudo yum install openproject

The installation completed.  and then I needed to run the config (which I also did from the whm terminal.
I didn't add a new apache2 server or memcached my server already had those. for the FQDN (fully qualified domain. I set it to projects.example.dev. The config confirmed it connected to the database but there was this error:
PG::UndefinedFile: ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/pgsql/extension/btree_gist.control": No such file or directory (PG::UndefinedFile)

nothing loads at the live url either.
Clearly I've done something (or multiple things) wrong.  What can I do to fix this?

the step "I installed postgres" isn't completed. Obviously you will need the btree_gist extension. See the doc of your host for how to install it.

@jgh Thank you. that fixed my error and the install completed successfully.  Still nothing loads at the assigned url.  IS there anything else to try?
